# App is changing default application for specific file type

Tags: default-programs, file-type, franz

I'm trying to resolve a problem that, whenever I run Franz (https://meetfranz.com/), it changes the default application for .html files to Franz. I believe Franz is built based on electron.js so maybe it has something to do with that.

I've created a github issue (https://github.com/meetfranz/franz/issues/1447), however, the developers say they do not implement such a feature.

Is there anything else in the OS happening, that could lead to such a change?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.